# Game Client's Listening Server Unable To Establish A Successful TCP Connection (Updated)

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, hosting

### Scenario, A Risk of Rain

On a game called "Risk of Rain" (RoR), I am hosting my own listening server. However to my demise, it seems that nobody can successfully join my server. I have done the basic prerequisites such as correct port-forwarding but still no avail.

As such, I have conducted numerous other tests to narrow down the problem but I cannot identify the root cause. The simple diagram below represents essentially the network:

**ISP (Time Warner Cable)** <----------------> **Linksys WRT610N Router** <---------------> **My Computer**

As for the tests that I have conducted and relevant important information, they are summarized below corresponding to each network device:

### ***My Computer***

- My antivirus, windows firewall & defender are all temporarily disabled
- Verified integrity of game cache (via a digital distribution application called "Steam" [since I bought the game from Steam])

### ***Linksys WRT610N Router***

1. Setting my PC to DMZ did not solve the issue
2. I am able to telnet connect to my server via the loopback IP & my
   own internal IP
3. Using any other game to host a listening server works with the current port-forwarding settings on my router
4. I am able to join a listening server hosted by anyone other than myself
5. My router's firewall is disabled
6. I am hosting on port "11100" which isn't being already used by any other application (checked via netstat)
7. "netstat" in cmd is stating that the game is indeed establishing a "Listening" TCP connection (however no one can successfully join my server)
8. When I host the listening server on a specific port and attempt a port scan via online websites, the results indicate that a firewall is blocking any inbound connection to that specific port

### ***ISP (Time Warner Cable)***

- No actions done over here

**My deductions:** To start with, the problem does seem to be NAT related due to ***1***, ***2***, ***3***. Additionally, it doesn't seem to be a software based issue since ***2*** works and since the game cache has been verified. On a different note, ***8*** is implying that a firewall is still present. The only firewall that can be present is from the ISP. However, why is it that only RoR does not work on this specific network socket while other similar games do? Am I mistaken or neglecting any other possible factors/roots?

---

### Question

Simply put, people cannot join my listening server. With all the tests I carried out above, what is the root cause of this issue and how can I resolve it?

Windows 7 
 
Linksys WRT610N emulator: http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT610N/1.00.00.17/index.htm

Comment: Do you have uPnP enabled on your router...?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply; this problem is not actually mine but someone I am trying to assist (he hasn't replied as to whether his uPnP is enabled). As for my response, the default setting on WRT610N is to enable uPnP on the router. If uPnP is indeed the culprit, why and how so?

Comment: 'Risk of Rain' can use uPNP to gain additional network (WAN-side ) awareness, and possibly notify an InternetGatewayDevice about additional server ports to open.

Comment: One way of taking NAT port mappings out of the equation is to set the server as a DMZ host on the router.  This places the host designated in the router in the Demilitarized Zone, exposing it to the public Internet as though it had the Public IP of the router's WAN port, and so would receive all connection requests on any port.   Of course, this passively exposes the host to the entire Internet, and so if it happens to be vulnerable to any common scanning attacks, it will surely be compromised.   However, setting up a DMZ host will quickly indicate a NAT problem.

Comment: When possible, I will confirm and test out the uPnP setting on his router. As for the DMZ, if I set it up and it did indeed highlight NAT problem, is there any method other than port forwarding, uPnP & DMZ that can make his NAT more 'open'? I am avoiding DMZ due to inherient security vunerabilities as you mentioned but I cannot seem to find other settings that influence NAT for that specific router (WRT610; online emulator: http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT610N/1.00.00.17/index.htm)

Comment: There aren't really a great deal of settings wrt NAT, really.  What OS are you on, btw..?

Have you checked to see if the server's host is listening on port 11100 when the server software is started?  (running 'netstat -an' is pretty universal, and ought to give a line in a list that looks something like Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    '
...
tcp4       0      0  *.11100                 *.*                    LISTEN     


Can a local client connect to the RoR server...?

Comment: He is using windows 7. Yes, the host is indeed listening on port 11100 as checked by netstat. As for a local client being able to connect, unfortunately I believe he does not have the resources to do test that out (i.e. another PC with RoR on it is not available).

Comment: Telnet 127.0.0.1 11100 from the server ought to establish a connection.

Comment: uPnP as expected was already enabled on his router. Additionally, telnet was able to establish a successful connection to the game client server (verified via netstat).

Answer (score 0):

With the additional information supplied, it would appear that the router is not configured properly for NAT port forwarding, or, the service is not working as expected.

Using the supplied emulator, I notice that the inside private IP has to be specified for the port forwarding.  This means that under `Basic Setup`, a <kbd>DHCP Reservation</kbd> ought to be set-up to ensure that the game server has the same IP address, such that when the `Single Port Forwarding` is configured, the reserved IP address can be supplied.  I believe `External Port` and `Internal Port` should be set to `11100`, <kbd>Both</kbd>, the IP number set, and the  <kbd>Enabled</kbd>  box checked.

Should these settings already be in place, ensure the router has the latest software.  Power-cycle the router, and if a remote connection on port 11100 still cannot be established, contact your ISP for technical support.

Comment: New information has been added to my question above (I have performed more tests). Unfortunately, the IP address on the hosting machine is already static and port-forwarded as noted in your answer. Although, I have yet to update the router's software and contact my ISP however as mentioned in the new updated question, it doesn't seem to be a NAT issue.

Comment: The a brief DMZ test may be telling; perhaps the ISP has restrictions?

Also, I think you meant 'dismay';  'demise' means 'death'. :)

Comment: I am not aware of any restrictions that the ISP (Warner Time Cable) has in place. However, I will contact them when available and double check. Additionally, I will also try as a test to use an encrypted VPN or some form of encryption to bypass the ISP restrictions (if indeed that is the case). Ah yes, "dismay" is probably the word I was looking for and hence I have edited above. I was hoping that I can get away with 'demise' in terms of semantics/connotation but it seems I have been misusing the word :o. Thanks for pointing that out =)

Comment: Oh one more thing, if it does indeed turn out to be the ISP, then why is it that some of my games work using the same network socket while others don't?

Comment: You run other game servers using port 11100 ?

Comment: Yup, and it works perfectly fine. I also tested it out with other port numbers such as "7777" which worked with other games but did not work with Risk of Rain